# So many errors when trying to install RobotJS through "npm install robotjs". Any idea whether I'm missing some dependency or something else?

Tags: node.js, npm, robotjs

### When I run `npm install robotjs` I get a huge error message (pasted at the bottom).

### So far, I've tried:

- purging and reinstalling node

```
apt-get purge nodejs 
rm -r /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list 
curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

- downgrading node from 18.x.0 to 16.16.0

`sudo -E env "PATH=$PATH" n stable`

- installing the build-essentials

`apt-get install -y build-essential`

- Installing x11 library

`sudo apt-get install libx11-dev`

I'm at a loss here, if anyone can point me in some direction.

---

## System Info

Distributor ID: Ubuntu

Description:   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Release:   22.04

Codename:  jammy

---

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/alexei/coding-projects/repos/slither-bot/node_modules/robotjs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/alexei/coding-projects/repos/slither-bot/node_modules/robotjs/build'
npm ERR!   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/robotjs.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/deadbeef_rand.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/mouse.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/keypress.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/keycode.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/screen.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/screengrab.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/snprintf.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/MMBitmap.o
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs/src/xdisplay.o
npm ERR!   SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/robotjs.node
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/home/alexei/coding-projects/repos/slither-bot/node_modules/robotjs/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.16.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.4 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/alexei/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/alexei/coding-projects/repos/slither-bot/node_modules/robotjs/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/alexei/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/alexei/.cache/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/alexei/.cache/node-gyp/16.16.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/alexei/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/alexei/.cache/node-gyp/16.16.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/alexei/coding-projects/repos/slither-bot/node_modules/robotjs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! cc1plus: warning: command-line option ‘-Wbad-function-cast’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
npm ERR! In file included from ../src/robotjs.cc:1:
npm ERR! /home/alexei/.cache/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/node.h:847:7: warning: cast between incompatible function types from ‘void (*)(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’} to ‘node::addon_register_func’ {aka ‘void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, void*)’} [-Wcast-function-type]
npm ERR!   847 |       (node::addon_register_func) (regfunc),                          \
npm ERR!       |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! /home/alexei/.cache/node-gyp/16.16.0/include/node/node.h:881:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE_X’
npm ERR!   881 |   NODE_MODULE_X(modname, regfunc, NULL, 0)  // NOLINT (readability/null_usage)
npm ERR!       |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/robotjs.cc:907:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘NODE_MODULE’
npm ERR!   907 | NODE_MODULE(robotjs, InitAll)
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/robotjs.cc: In function ‘Nan::NAN_METHOD_RETURN_TYPE keyToggle(Nan::NAN_METHOD_ARGS_TYPE)’:
npm ERR! ../src/robotjs.cc:592:38: warning: ‘down’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
npm ERR!   592 |                         toggleKeyCode(key, down, flags);
npm ERR!       |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189,
npm ERR!                  from ../../nan/nan.h:294,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/robotjs.cc:2:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h: In function ‘void InitAll(Nan::ADDON_REGISTER_FUNCTION_ARGS_TYPE)’:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:119:1: warning: inlining failed in call to ‘static Nan::imp::FactoryBase<v8::FunctionTemplate>::return_t Nan::imp::Factory<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New.constprop(Nan::FunctionCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Signature>)’: --param large-function-growth limit reached [-Winline]
npm ERR!   119 | Factory<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New( FunctionCallback callback
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:294,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/robotjs.cc:2:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_new.h:239:32: note: called from here
npm ERR!   239 |     return imp::Factory<T>::New(callback, data);
npm ERR!       |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan_new.h:189,
npm ERR!                  from ../../nan/nan.h:294,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/robotjs.cc:2:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_implementation_12_inl.h:119:1: warning: inlining failed in call to ‘static Nan::imp::FactoryBase<v8::FunctionTemplate>::return_t Nan::imp::Factory<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New.constprop(Nan::FunctionCallback, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Signature>)’: --param large-function-growth limit reached [-Winline]
npm ERR!   119 | Factory<v8::FunctionTemplate>::New( FunctionCallback callback
npm ERR!       | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! In file included from ../../nan/nan.h:294,
npm ERR!                  from ../src/robotjs.cc:2:
npm ERR! ../../nan/nan_new.h:239:32: note: called from here
npm ERR!   239 |     return imp::Factory<T>::New(callback, data);
npm ERR!       |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/keypress.c: In function ‘typeString’:
npm ERR! ../src/keypress.c:259:39: warning: ‘n’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
npm ERR!   259 |         #define toggleUniKey(c, down) toggleKey(c, down, MOD_NONE)
npm ERR!       |                                       ^~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/keypress.c:274:23: note: ‘n’ was declared here
npm ERR!   274 |         unsigned long n;
npm ERR!       |                       ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c: In function ‘portable_vsnprintf’:
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:557:35: warning: operand of ‘?:’ changes signedness from ‘long int’ to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} due to unsignedness of other operand [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   557 |       size_t n = !q ? strlen(p) : (q-p);
npm ERR!       |                                   ^~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:704:42: warning: operand of ‘?:’ changes signedness from ‘long int’ to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} due to unsignedness of other operand [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   704 |             str_arg_l = !q ? precision : (q-str_arg);
npm ERR!       |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:943:62: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   943 |             fast_memset(str+str_l, (zero_padding?'0':' '), (n>avail?avail:n));
npm ERR!       |                                                              ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:372:35: note: in definition of macro ‘fast_memset’
npm ERR!   372 |   { register size_t nn = (size_t)(n); \
npm ERR!       |                                   ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:943:75: warning: operand of ‘?:’ changes signedness from ‘int’ to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} due to unsignedness of other operand [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   943 |             fast_memset(str+str_l, (zero_padding?'0':' '), (n>avail?avail:n));
npm ERR!       |                                                                           ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:372:35: note: in definition of macro ‘fast_memset’
npm ERR!   372 |   { register size_t nn = (size_t)(n); \
npm ERR!       |                                   ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:960:47: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   960 |             fast_memcpy(str+str_l, str_arg, (n>avail?avail:n));
npm ERR!       |                                               ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:365:35: note: in definition of macro ‘fast_memcpy’
npm ERR!   365 |   { register size_t nn = (size_t)(n); \
npm ERR!       |                                   ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:960:60: warning: operand of ‘?:’ changes signedness from ‘int’ to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} due to unsignedness of other operand [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   960 |             fast_memcpy(str+str_l, str_arg, (n>avail?avail:n));
npm ERR!       |                                                            ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:365:35: note: in definition of macro ‘fast_memcpy’
npm ERR!   365 |   { register size_t nn = (size_t)(n); \
npm ERR!       |                                   ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:969:43: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   969 |             fast_memset(str+str_l, '0', (n>avail?avail:n));
npm ERR!       |                                           ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:372:35: note: in definition of macro ‘fast_memset’
npm ERR!   372 |   { register size_t nn = (size_t)(n); \
npm ERR!       |                                   ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:969:56: warning: operand of ‘?:’ changes signedness from ‘int’ to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} due to unsignedness of other operand [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   969 |             fast_memset(str+str_l, '0', (n>avail?avail:n));
npm ERR!       |                                                        ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:372:35: note: in definition of macro ‘fast_memset’
npm ERR!   372 |   { register size_t nn = (size_t)(n); \
npm ERR!       |                                   ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:981:27: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   981 |                         (n>avail?avail:n));
npm ERR!       |                           ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:365:35: note: in definition of macro ‘fast_memcpy’
npm ERR!   365 |   { register size_t nn = (size_t)(n); \
npm ERR!       |                                   ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:981:40: warning: operand of ‘?:’ changes signedness from ‘int’ to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} due to unsignedness of other operand [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   981 |                         (n>avail?avail:n));
npm ERR!       |                                        ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:365:35: note: in definition of macro ‘fast_memcpy’
npm ERR!   365 |   { register size_t nn = (size_t)(n); \
npm ERR!       |                                   ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:992:43: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: ‘int’ and ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   992 |             fast_memset(str+str_l, ' ', (n>avail?avail:n));
npm ERR!       |                                           ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:372:35: note: in definition of macro ‘fast_memset’
npm ERR!   372 |   { register size_t nn = (size_t)(n); \
npm ERR!       |                                   ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:992:56: warning: operand of ‘?:’ changes signedness from ‘int’ to ‘size_t’ {aka ‘long unsigned int’} due to unsignedness of other operand [-Wsign-compare]
npm ERR!   992 |             fast_memset(str+str_l, ' ', (n>avail?avail:n));
npm ERR!       |                                                        ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:372:35: note: in definition of macro ‘fast_memset’
npm ERR!   372 |   { register size_t nn = (size_t)(n); \
npm ERR!       |                                   ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:564:19: warning: variable ‘starting_p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
npm ERR!   564 |       const char *starting_p;
npm ERR!       |                   ^~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:369:48: warning: ‘str_arg’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
npm ERR!   369 |       for (ss=(s), dd=(d); nn>0; nn--) *dd++ = *ss++; } }
npm ERR!       |                                                ^
npm ERR! ../src/snprintf.c:573:19: note: ‘str_arg’ was declared here
npm ERR!   573 |       const char *str_arg;      /* string address in case of string argument */
npm ERR!       |                   ^~~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/xdisplay.c: In function ‘setXDisplay’:
npm ERR! ../src/xdisplay.c:53:23: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strdup’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
npm ERR!    53 |         displayName = strdup(name);
npm ERR!       |                       ^~~~~~
npm ERR! ../src/xdisplay.c:53:23: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strdup’ [-Wbuiltin-declaration-mismatch]
npm ERR! /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpng: No such file or directory
npm ERR! /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz: No such file or directory
npm ERR! collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
npm ERR! make: *** [robotjs.target.mk:173: Release/obj.target/robotjs.node] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/alexei/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:194:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-43-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/alexei/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/bin/node" "/home/alexei/.nvm/versions/node/v16.16.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/alexei/coding-projects/repos/slither-bot/node_modules/robotjs
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.0.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/alexei/.npm/_logs/2022-08-05T00_18_42_282Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Seems like you're missing needed libraries.  both libpng and libz seem to be missing or npm can't find it in the standard lib dirs.

Answer (score 0):

Per ewong's comment, solved this one by installing the libpng and libz libraries.

```
sudo apt-get install libpng-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
```